# When using chainlink automation, can another person call my performUpKeep function of smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

Does chainlink automation use my performUpKeep function even though there is onlyOwner modifier ? If so can another person call performUpKeep function of my smart contract ?

```
I was using chainlink automation on my smart contract function. And i thought if chainlink automation can use my smart contract function directly, can another person call it ? Is chainlink automation safe ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Tuvshuu kun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20449459/tuvshuu-kun)

No, the `performUpKeep` function will not work if you add an `onlyOwner` modifier, if the address is who deployed the contract (concept of owner).

But you can restrict it using `onlyKeeperRegistry`.

The [EthBalanceMonitor Contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-automation/utility-contracts/) use this concept, it can be useful for you :)